# Lenor scent boosters leaving white marks on clothes

Tags: clothing, laundry

Since I started using Lenor (blue) unstoppables in the wash, it’s leaving white spots on dark clothing which if I don’t spot it immediately & ‘rub’ means it needs washing again.

I’m following instructions to put in the drum before loading the laundry.

Any ideas or others coming across the same thing?

Thanks

Comment: I have not used it, but IMO the best hack would be to stop using – find a different product.

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks. <rant> Please stop using this phthalate loaded product which pollutes our air and water. The odor is an indicator of a chemical contaminant not any measure of clean (which has no odor). Don't put it into the drum—Better, put it into hazardous materials. [https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8157593/] </rant>

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me but I loved the smell so much I didn’t want to stop using them so the only thing I could think of to do was to dissolve the scent balls in some hot water first then add them when the wash starts.